# No $g$ is not $onto$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is the given proof of the following theorem correct.

**Theorem.** If $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to A$ and $f \circ g = i_B$ but $g \circ f \neq i_A$, then $g$ is not *onto*.

**Proof.** Assume that $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to A$, $f \circ g = i_B$, $g\circ f\neq i_A$ and that $g$ is *onto*. $g\circ f\neq i_A$ implies that for some $a\in A$, $g(f(a))\neq i_A(a)=a$ since $f:A\to B$ it follows that for some $b\in B$ it must be the case that 
$$f(a)=b\ (1)$$ 
we may now state our earlier inference more precisely as follows
$$g(b)\neq a\ (2)$$
by the same reasoning we can conclude that $g(b)=a'$ for some $a'\in A$, evidently $a\neq a'$ but $g$ is *onto* so for some $b'\in B$,  $g(b')=a$ and since $g:B\to A$ and $a\neq a'$ it must be that $$b\neq b'\ (3)$$ moreover $f\circ g=i_B$ then in particular for $b'$ we see that $f(g(b'))=f(a)=i_B(b')=b'$ i.e.
$$f(a)=b'\ (4)$$
Taking $(1)$ and $(4)$ together we may conclude that $b=b'$ but this contradicts $(3)$ thus $g$ is not *onto*.

Comment: Small formatting tip: `\tag{1}` in a displayed equation creates an equation number (1). :)

Comment: Perfect.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof  is correct. However, I think it can be simplified, by proving the contrapositive : if $g$ is onto, then $g \circ f = i_A$. So assume that $g$ is onto.

Since $f \circ g = i_B$, $f$ is injective. This is because $f(a) = f(b) \implies f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$, where $g(x) =a$ and $g(y) =b$,  this implies $x=y$, and hence $a=b$.

Hence,for any $x$, $g(f(x)) = x$, since $f(g(f(x))) = f(x)$, and $f$ is injective, so $g(f(x)) = x$. Hence $g \circ f = i_A$, and so the contrapositive is proven.

Comment: The contrapositive is a very useful way of rewriting statements to make them clearer. Of course one could go by contradiction, as you have done, so I'll give a +1 for your attempt on this question.